# Custom admin module with listing and file uploading

Tags: magento-1.9

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Pant>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </My_Pant>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <my_pant>
                <class>My_Pant_Helper</class>
            </my_pant>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <my_pant>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Pant</module>
                    <frontName>pant</frontName>
                </args>
            </my_pant>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>

      <menu>
        <my_menu translate="title" module="my_pant">
            <title>pankaj</title>
            <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
            <action>pant/index/index</action>

        </my_menu>
    </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**IndexControllers**

```
<?php
class My_Pant_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('<h1>hello  bye</h1>');
        $this->_addContent($block);

        $this->_setActiveMenu('my_menu')->renderLayout();      
    }   

}
```

This is successfully run: output-> hello bye.

But I need to create custom admin module with listing and file upload.

Comment: what u mean by `listing and file upload`?

Comment: @AmitBera it's mean grid and form..

Comment: yes.. grid with form..& it should have option to browse image (upload, delete & edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use/install any existing (and FREE) extension that suits (OR partially suits) your requirements. And then remove unwanted functionality from this extension. This will save much time and effort.

I'll suggest this FREE slideshow extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dolphin-responsive-slideshow.html

check this file `app\design\frontend\default\default\template\slideshow\slideshow.phtml`, you can get collection by `$bannerCollections = Mage::getModel('slideshow/slideshow')->getCollection()`

If you are using 1.9.x, you should add `slideshow/slideshow` to `System > Permission > Blocks`

Hope this helps

Comment: thanx... but i only need form with image upload through admin panel from my custom admin module......

Comment: This extension has this feature to upload image with title and also shows listing/grid with image.

Comment: I have installed it... Do you try this extension ..?? Is uploaded image can also show in front-end... ??

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: i have create one item:  TITLE: my image, URL: mynew , IMAGE FILE: abc.jpg, STATUS : Enable ... Now, My question is that "How to show this image in front end.. ?

Comment: please check `slideshow.phtml` file, code for showing image (with data) is there

Comment: thanks..@Anil...i have integrate 2 more functionality in it, massDelete & massStatus..

Comment: that's great, Pankaj, Have you any issues ?

Comment: yes there is one issue...but  i have solved. ...which is related to massStatus... enable - disable problem...

Comment: ys, I can add this to answer. There's 1=Enable and 0=Disable

Comment: Posted Complete Answer here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115093/disable-status-problem-in-magento-admin-grid/115107#115107

Comment: validation is not working in image file...  $fieldset->addField('filename', 'image', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Image File'),
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'filename',
     ));

Comment: now it is working ... i have replaced image with file.

Comment: In this module, sorting is not working under admin grid...how to sort out this issue..?

Answer (score 1):

Pankaj,Of one answer,it does not possible to ***learn How to implement grid & Form*** .
You need to study **How admin grid /form** are implemented  at magento.

**For reference,you can follow below blogs**

- [excellencemagentoblog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/26/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs/)
- [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/)