# Disable Status problem in magento admin grid

Tags: magento-1.9

below code is _prepareMassaction() in grid.php

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
         $this->setMassactionIdField('slideshow_id');
         $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('slideshow');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Delete'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),

        ));

     $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('slideshow/status')->getOptionArray();

    //print_r($statuses); die;

        array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Change status'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
             'additional' => array(
                    'visibility' => array(
                         'name' => 'status',
                         'type' => 'select',
                         'class' => 'required-entry',
                         'label' => Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Status'),
                         'values' => $statuses
        )
        )
        ));
        return $this;
    }
```

Below code in massStatusAction() in my controller.

```
public function massStatusAction()
    {
        $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('slideshow');
        //print_r($ids); die;
        if(!is_array($ids)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select checkbox'));
        } else {
            try {
                foreach ($ids as $id) {

                    //print_r($id); die;
                   Mage::getSingleton('slideshow/slideshow')
                        ->load($id)
                        ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status'))
                        ->setIsMassupdate(true)
                        ->save();
                }
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($ids))
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }
```

When i changes action from disable to enable it successfully changes. but again when i change status from enable to disable. it not changes my status.

Comment: What is the input you are passing at $this->getRequest()->getParam('status'), it should be 1=enable and 2=disable. Most people assume 0 is for disable, not sure what is in your case

Comment: $this->addColumn('status', array(
     
                'header'    => Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Status'),
                'align'     => 'left',
                'width'     => '80px',
                'index'     => 'status',
                'type'      => 'options',
                'options'   => array(
                    1 => 'Enable',
                    0 => 'Disable',
                )
            ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, its obvious you are passing 0 for disable. In Magento this should work with disable value as 2

Your code can be rewrite as per below

```
$this->addColumn('status', array( 'header' => Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Status'), 'align' => 'left', 'width' => '80px', 'index' => 'status', 'type' => 'options', 'options' => array( 1 => 'Enable', 2 => 'Disable', ) ));
```

Comment: @duke..from which php file  ...getParam('status') is coming..it grid.php or form.php --> setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status'))

Comment: Usually it comes from _prepareColumns functions should be in Grid.php

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to `app\code\community\Dolphin\Slideshow\Block\Adminhtml\Slideshow\Grid.php`

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('slideshow_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('status');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('enable_slides', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Enable Slides'),
        'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massEnable'),
    ));
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('disable_slides', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Disable Slides'),
        'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDisable'),
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

Add this actions to `app\code\community\Dolphin\Slideshow\controllers\Adminhtml\IndexController.php`

```
public function massEnableAction()
{
    $slideIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');
    if(!is_array($slideIds)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Please select Slide(s)'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($slideIds as $slideId) 
            {
                $slidesModelInner = Mage::getModel('slideshow/slideshow')->load($slideId);
                $slidesModelInner->setStatus(1)->save();
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Total of %d slides(s) were successfully enabled',count($slideIds))
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
public function massDisableAction()
{
    $slideIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');
    if(!is_array($slideIds)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Please select Slide(s)'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($slideIds as $slideId) 
            {
                $slidesModelInner = Mage::getModel('slideshow/slideshow')->load($slideId);
                $slidesModelInner->setStatus(0)->save();
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('slideshow')->__('Total of %d slides(s) were successfully disabled',count($slideIds))
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

This will look like this:

[image]